# Getting the longest string (ending by a newline) out of a Textarea in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, string, split, textarea

This somehow simple task is not so simple.
I can get the number of lines of the textarea using mx:internals, but thats is not always the longest line ending by a newline.

I tried all sort of `textArea.text.split("\n")  \r  <br/> {/n ..`
It always returns me the length of 1.

My eternal worshipping to anyone who can put me in the right direction.

Greg

==========

```
var arr:Array = texCodeArea.text.split(/\n/);
trace(arr.length);
trace("TEXT iS :", texCodeArea.text, "END");
```

==========

```
1
TEXT iS : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb 
cccccc END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use /\r/ instead of /\n/.

Not sure why; it just works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
textArea.text.split(/\n/);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

s.split(/\r\n/);